# opencv error while running facial recognition code

Tags: python, opencv

I am following an opencv tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmZ29Vta7Vc

At 11:36 when he runs his code, it works fine, but when I run my code, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joshua/OneDrive/VscodePrograms/MyPythonFolder/facialRec/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('casades/data/haardcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print(x, y, w, h)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please help!

Comment: Maybe your XML file was not found. Are you sure you entered a valid path/file?

Comment: @eldesgraciado yes I copied the name and pasted it into the string again but I still get the error

Comment: Enter the absolute XML path and use "\\" instead of "\".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the CascadeClassifier's path:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
```

I think now it should be working fine.